# Negative energy and time translations in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy

One can define the energy operator of a quantum system as the Hamiltonian operator when it is time-independent, $H(t)=H$, so that energy is constant for a system with time-translation invariance. With this very definition, can one discard the existence of negative energies? Namely, that $H$ may have unbounded negative spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

The spectral condition is an axiom of QM/QFT and not something that can be derived from first principles.

As for the question, assume that $H$ is a time-invariant self-adjoint operator with bounded negative spectrum. Then $-H$ is a time-invariant self-adjoint operator with bounded positive spectrum. Therefore, time-invariance alone is not enough to limit spectra in one or another direction.

Comment: My feeling is that if the evolution is time-translation invariant, then it only depends on the difference $\tau=t_2-t_1$ between final $t_2$ and initial $t_1$ time instants. If we consider this as positive and $H$ with negative bounded spectrum, for a $-H$ the evolution would be kind of backwards. So a negative bounded spectrum could be a consequence to the usual convention that $t_2>t_1$ if the events at $t_2$ happens after events at $t_1$ (or something like that..)